# Восстановление актуального состояния системы после отката

Tags: windows-7

Файл, который был очень важен удален вчера. Хотел бы его вернуть.
Есть вариант откатиться до контрольной точки трехдневной давности с помощью восстановления системы.
И вот вопрос: ***Можно ли после восстановления, вернуться к актуальному на сегодня состоянию моей системы?***
Заранее признателен.

Comment: Ну если создать еще одну точку восстановления: сегодняшнюю - почему бы и нет. А если хочется быть совсем уверенным, то можно вообще через TrueImage создать архивную копию системного диска, сохранить где-либо и потом восстановить непосредственно из неё (все с той же программы True Image) ......но вообще смотря где удаленный файл хранился и был ли подключен к данному диску восставление

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не надо создавать. Она сама создастся при восстановлении. А если создать вручную, то некоторая старая (самая старая из имеющихся) может удалиться. И этой старой может оказаться как раз та трёхдневной давности - это если на диске места мало, либо если лимит на место под контрольные точки закончился (вроде 12% по умолчанию).

Comment: @Qwertiy то есть при восстановлении вновь создаваемая точка не перезатрёт одну старых из точек, а при создании вручную сотрёт? Очень интересно...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не уверен про восстановление - может затереть тоже. В другом мысль. Если она создаётся сама - то она одна. Если ты создаёшь вручную, то при откате автоматически создастся ещё одна - и их уже две - вероятность затереть повышается. К тому же, вряд ли он затрёт то, к чему откатывается. Хотя, кажется у меня были ситуации, что точка исчезала после отката и возврата обратно. Есть вариант, что он сначала откатится, а потом сотрёт, например. В общем, не знаю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно ведь просто перед откатом увеличить память для хранимых данных контрольных точек.

Comment: @dors это не мне надо говорить, вероятно ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пользовательские файлы обычно неподконтрольны восстановлению системы.
2. В большинстве случаев откат до контрольной точки создают ещё одну контрольную точку с состоянием на текущий момент. К ней можно будет потом вернуться.
3. Скорее всего, на самом деле стоит воспользоваться программой для восстановления удалённых файлов типа [Recuva](http://filehippo.com/download_recuva/).

Comment: Разве в винде нет настройки восстановления системы для каждого диска? Там же в свойствах системы можно задавать, или нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, для каждого диска - да есть. Если не ошибаюсь, в семёрке во умолчанию включен только системный, а в XP все. В любом случае, дело не в этом. Под восстановление попадают только исполняемые и некие подобные им файлы - exe, dll, cab, не помню, что ещё. Всякие txt, docx - не попадают. Это сделано, чтобы при откате пользователь не потерял свои файлы - откат должен влиять только на программы. Вроде бы есть ещё нечто с версионированием, что может откатывать состояние конкретных файлов, но я этим ни разу не пользовался. К тому же, говорят, в семёрке эта технология была ещё сырой.

Comment: @Qwertiy увы файлы не получилось откатить, но спасибо за подсказку, в какую сторону смотреть)